# Looking for a test string with a char from all languages

Tags: testing, internationalization

For I18n testing, I'm looking for a test string that have a good representation of all commonly used languages (supported by UTF-8) and have all the special chars of these languages that normally have issues in display.

Will use this test string to keep sure that our system process these languages correctly and have the correct font that can display all these languages correctly.

E.g. the sample text should have chars from latin languages, Far East Languages, right to left languages...

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer to your question, as it is full of ambiguous terms, for instance "commonly used languages" or "normally have issues in display". This is highly dependent on OS, OS version, the text engine used to display the text, fonts installed. Pretty much the whole tech stack.

Sprinkling "all" in the question (all the special chars, all ... languages) make any answer useless.
You will looking at a string of tens thousands of characters. Then you have a lot of combining marks, and ligatures. Do you want to check all of those combinations too? Those might also have "issues in display"

If all you want to do is check that your application works in (most) languages, try taking some (not all) characters from each Unicode block. Might also want to avoid historical scripts (i.e. cuneiform, Egyptian hieroglyphs, etc.) the are not covered by common fonts.

In general, if you application does not corrupt the string somehow, it will render properly. And if it does not, then it is not your app at fault, it is some limitation in the underlying technology (i.e. the Windows console)

If you explain what you are trying to do, you might get a better answer.
Or you can just search for internationalization testing.

Comment: Sorry if my question looked ambiguous to you. I'm looking for a sample text that contains language samples to test with. E.g. Latin languages can be tested by è. Japanese with あ, Arabic أهلا and so on. I can come up with a  Sample chars for some  languages, but not for all languages that is supported by UTF-8. I want to use this text to test the backend and the font that I'm using in my browser(s) can display these languages. I'm working in web app with backend that uses many technologies (Java, Node, JS, Cassandra, ES...). Using this text will help to discover any issues of any layer.

Comment: It is ambiguous in that it uses words without a clear definition. What is "commonly used language"? 30 million speakers? 10? 5?

Comment: Same for "normally have issues". "Normally" depends heavily on OS and technology stack.

Comment: Then the use of "all". Your example uses one character for Arabic, one for Japanese. But you asked for "all the special chars", and that means thousands on characters for Japanese

Comment: Assuming what you want is securely "being reasonably confident" that you can render content in "most" languages, I have recommended an approach: go by Unicode blocks and take 1-2 characters from each. This does not solve your request for "all characters", but it is reasonable. There is no good reason for two Japanese characters to show and for other 7000 not to show, unless your code damages them somehow, or are very rare and not present in the font.